# Mysql case statement affecting all rows of a table

Tags: mysql

I have a situaiton that has me a bit confused.  im using a case statement to update certain rows of a table.  the sql query is below,  however  if i do not specify a value for the column schema_value,  then the query will clear it out to null.    Here is a copy of the query and table    When the query is run,  it will null out initialized and test.

any ideas?

```
UPDATE vals
        SET valu
        CASE 
        When name = 'sitename' THEN '$siteame'
        When name = 'street' THEN '$stret' 
        When name = 'city' THEN '$cit'
        When name = 'State' THEN '$sate'
        When name = 'zipcode' THEN '$ipcode'
        When name = 'phone' THEN '$pone'
        When name = 'fax' THEN '$fx'
        When name = 'social' THEN '$ocial'
        END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add an else statement if nothing matches it should keep the original data

```
UPDATE schema_vals
        SET schema_value = 
        CASE 
        When schema_name = 'sitename' THEN '$siteame'
        When schema_name = 'street' THEN '$stret' 
        When schema_name = 'city' THEN '$cit'
        When schema_name = 'State' THEN '$sate'
        When schema_name = 'zipcode' THEN '$ipcode'
        When schema_name = 'phone' THEN '$pone'
        When schema_name = 'fax' THEN '$fx'
        When schema_name = 'social' THEN '$ocial'
        ELSE schema_value
        END;
```

Comment: Yes, I had finally just found documentation on this.  I came to delete the question since its been answered so well leave it as it may help someone in the future!  Thanks